# Connect Delphi mobile app to web server via HTTPS/TLS

Tags: android, database, delphi, https, firemonkey

What is the easiest and most secure way to connect to a remote web server using HTTPS/TLS in a Delphi FireMonkey app? Are there any components available for this purpose?

I need the mobile app to connect a web server so that it can synchronise the phone's local database with the server's database. To achieve this, I envision using transferring database records in XML via the secure HTTPS connection. Is this the best way to go about this?

Comment: Personally, I would use JSON, not XML. But that's just me. This question is unfortunately off-topic on Stack Overflow for more than one reason.

Comment: I would use still XML. You can create your web service methods (in *.asmx files)  then you can import WSDL from Component>Import WSDL to Delphi IDE. Then you handle your connection and data transfer between web server and your FireMonkey app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi ships with Indy pre-installed, which has a `TIdHTTP` component for communicating with HTTP/S servers.